# Why can't emacs elisp function 'search-forward' find carriage return characters anymore?

Tags: emacs, newline, eol, dos2unix

This code for dos2unix conversion in an emacs buffer stopped working at some point. I've been using it since the 90's (emacs 19) and I don't know exactly when it stopped working.

```lisp
;;; Dos to Unix conversion in buffer
(defun dos2unix ()
  "convert <CR><LF> characters in buffer to <LF>."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (while (search-forward "\015\012" nil t)
      (replace-match "\012" nil t))))
```

With windows emacs 27.2 or 25.3, in a file with known DOS line terminators (0x0d 0x0a), it simply doesn't find the carriage return characters.

I've tried searching separately for the carriage return and line feed characters. It finds the line feed characters just fine, but not the carriage returns.
I've tried other syntax variations: `\015`, `\x0d`, `\r`, `\C-m`, `(string ?\C-m)` and it just doesn't find them.
I've also tried using `re-search-forward` or `search-forward-regexp` in place of `search-forward`.

Comment: In case you find it nicer to read, you can alternatively write `"\015\012"` as `"\r\n"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If file in general has CRLF line endings, then Emacs recognises that and seamlessly uses that format without displaying the CR characters.  Similarly if there are only CRs and no LFs it will recognise that as the old MacOS format, and seamlessly display the file as if LFs were used, rather than as one long line.

The mode line shows the recognised syntax.  In your case you will see `(DOS)` in the bottom left of the mode line.  If you click that with your mouse, it will cycle through the three options (with the typical Unix style being displayed as just `:` for brevity).

If you switch to the Unix line endings the buffer will be modified as the CRs will be removed (which you can confirm via <kbd>M-x</kbd> `diff-buffer-with-file`), so you can then just save the buffer.

Clicking the mode line like that is calling this command:

```el
(defun mode-line-change-eol (event)
  "Cycle through the various possible kinds of end-of-line styles."
  (interactive "e")
  (with-selected-window (posn-window (event-start event))
    (let ((eol (coding-system-eol-type buffer-file-coding-system)))
      (set-buffer-file-coding-system
       (cond ((eq eol 0) 'dos) ((eq eol 1) 'mac) (t 'unix))))))
```

Hence code to do this directly would be:

```el
(set-buffer-file-coding-system 'unix)
```

Note that if the file contents are *ambiguous* about line-endings, then the inconsistencies will be visible and subject to your original code.

For instance if there was one case of CRLF in an otherwise Unix-like file, you would see that CR and your function would be able to replace it.

Hence you *might* want to update your function by firstly calling `set-buffer-file-coding-system` and then continuing as before.

See <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Text Coding` for more information.

Edit: Per the comments, any call to that function marks the buffer as modified, whereas you might not *actually* be making a change, so we want to do this conditionally:

```el
(unless (eq 0 (coding-system-eol-type buffer-file-coding-system))
  (set-buffer-file-coding-system 'unix))
```

Comment: Adding (set-buffer-file-coding-system 'unix) to the beginning of the function does allow it to work again. The only minor annoyance with that approach is that (set-buffer-file-coding-system 'unix) marks the buffer as modified even if no characters were changed (i.e., it had all unix line terminators to start with).  Whereas with the original function, I could tell if any line terminators were changed if the buffer was marked as modified.

Comment: Still cribbing from the same quoted function, `(unless (eq t (coding-system-eol-type buffer-file-coding-system)) (set-buffer-file-coding-system 'unix))` will avoid doing it unnecessarily.

Comment: That didn't work, but this does:  (if (not (eq buffer-file-coding-system 'undecided-unix)) (set-buffer-file-coding-system 'unix))   Thank you for the workaround to what I consider a bug.  Should be able to search for a \r regardless of coding-system!

Comment: Ah, yes, that last comment was wrong.  It should have been `eq 0` rather than `eq t` -- and I think you'd want that rather than what you've used; refer to `C-h f coding-system-eol-type`.

Comment: I've updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Also note that if you use `M-x find-file-literally` you would see all the CRs.  If you ever want to check the literal contents of a file, you can use that.  See the notes in `C-h i g (emacs)Visiting` for more info.